# Copy files to host from project folder and use them inside my container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file to build three different images from 3 different Dockerfiles.

In my project structure, I have some files that I want to copy to a specific folder in my host machine, because those files will be used by one of the containers.
I don´t want those folders to be inside of my container, because anytime I change something on one of the files, I need to build the image again.

Instead of using command line to copy the files from my project to the host machine, how how can it be done automatically when I run `docker-compose build`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately docker-compose has no such concept as pre- or post-scripts. The simplest way of achieving your goal would be creating a shell script which would copy the files and call docker-compose. If for some reason you are limited to calling docker-compose itself, you can create additional "setup" container to copy the files before starting other containers:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  # setup container copies files from the project directory PROJECT_DIR
  # to another directory HOST_DIR on the host machine
  setup:
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_DIR}:/project
      - ${HOST_DIR}:/host
    command: >
      sh -c "cp -R /project/* /host/"

  # service container depends on the setup container and uses files from
  # the host machine directory HOST_DIR mounted to CONTAINER_DIR
  service:
    image: alpine:latest
    depends_on:
      - setup
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_DIR}:${CONTAINER_DIR}
    command: >
      sh -c "ls ${CONTAINER_DIR}"
```